# javascript: getting email address' text in between @ and the dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Here's an email: mynick@myemail.com

I need to store in a variable: myemail

To do so, I'm doing:

```
<script>

var email = "mynick@myemail.com";
justMyemail = email.replace(/.*\@|\./gi,''); 
alert(justMyemail);

</script>
```

But the alert shows: myemailcom instead of myemail

What is wrong with the code? How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(email.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just get everything after `@` and before the last `.`

```
var myregexp = /@(.*)\./;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

Regarding what is wrong. You are replacing everything until `@` and also all dots `\.`

Also case insensitivity with your regex is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex isn't completely correct. This should do it: `@(.*?)\.`.
Of course this doesn't work if there is a subdomain included in the address.